# Remove columns in a dataset of float type where the proportion of duplicate values in each column exceeds a certain threshold

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Suppose there is a time series data set `df`, as shown below, I hope to write a function to delete columns whose duplicate values exceed the threshold (for example, set to `0.5`), for example, the number of `4.772234` in `val1` is more than half. So this column will definitely be dropped.

```
                 date      val1      val2      val3
0  2017-01-31 00:00:00  4.772234 -6.538462  1.101784
1  2017-02-28 00:00:00  4.772234 -6.538462  1.101784
2  2017-03-31 00:00:00  4.772234 -6.538462  1.101784
3  2017-04-30 00:00:00  4.772234 -6.538462  1.101784
4  2017-05-31 00:00:00  4.772234 -4.526749 -0.622730
5  2017-06-30 00:00:00  4.772234  0.000000 -1.033943
6  2017-07-31 00:00:00  4.772234  3.448276  0.253271
7  2017-08-31 00:00:00  6.997930 -1.666667 -0.526316
8  2017-09-30 00:00:00  4.247291  5.084746 -2.476190
9  2017-10-31 00:00:00  4.377417  0.000000 -0.462963
```

Please note: 1. `val2` and `val3` may also be deleted if the threshold is set very small. For example, if it is set to `0.3`, we see that `-6.538462` appears more than `4` times in `val2`, and the total number is `10`, so the `duplicate_ratio` reaches `0.4`, exceeding the threshold of `0.3`, and the column will be deleted. 2. Since `val1`, `val2` and `val3` is a floating point number, `freq_ratio = df.apply (lambda x: x.value_counts().iloc[0] / len(x))` doesn't seem to correctly calculate the proportion of duplicate values.

The following function is also not working out:

```
def remove_columns_with_too_many_duplicates(df, threshold=0.5):
    duplicate_ratio = df.duplicated(keep=False).mean()
    columns_to_remove = duplicate_ratio[duplicate_ratio > threshold].index
    df = df.drop(columns_to_remove, axis=1)
    return df
```

call the function:

```
df1 = df.copy()
df1 = df1.set_index('date')
remove_columns_with_too_many_duplicates(df1, threshold=0.3)
Out[30]: 
                         val3
date                         
2017-01-31 00:00:00  1.101784
2017-02-28 00:00:00  1.101784
2017-03-31 00:00:00  1.101784
2017-04-30 00:00:00  1.101784
2017-05-31 00:00:00 -0.622730
2017-06-30 00:00:00 -1.033943
2017-07-31 00:00:00  0.253271
2017-08-31 00:00:00 -0.526316
2017-09-30 00:00:00 -2.476190
2017-10-31 00:00:00 -0.462963
```

Or:

```
drop_columns = []
drop_threshold = 0.3  # define the percentage criterion for drop
for cols in df1.columns:
    df_count = df1[cols].value_counts().reset_index()
    df_count['drop_percentage'] = df_count[cols] / df1.shape[0]
    df_count['drop_criterion'] = df_count['drop_percentage'] > drop_threshold
    if True in df_count.drop_criterion.values:
        drop_columns.append(cols)
df2 = df1.drop(columns=drop_columns, axis=1)
df2
```

Out:

```
                        val3
date                         
2017-01-31 00:00:00  1.101784
2017-02-28 00:00:00  1.101784
2017-03-31 00:00:00  1.101784
2017-04-30 00:00:00  1.101784
2017-05-31 00:00:00 -0.622730
2017-06-30 00:00:00 -1.033943
2017-07-31 00:00:00  0.253271
2017-08-31 00:00:00 -0.526316
2017-09-30 00:00:00 -2.476190
2017-10-31 00:00:00 -0.462963
```

We see that `1.101784` appears `4` times in `val3`, so `freq_ratio` is `0.4`, which is greater than the threshold of `0.3`, but the column is not deleted.

Please help me to solve this problem? Thanks a lot at advance.

Sample data:

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

data = """
date,val1,val2,val3
2017-01-31 00:00:00,4.772234,-6.538462,1.101784
2017-02-28 00:00:00,4.772234,-6.538462,1.101784
2017-03-31 00:00:00,4.772234,-6.538462,1.101784
2017-04-30 00:00:00,4.772234,-6.538462,1.101784
2017-05-31 00:00:00,4.772234,-4.526749,-0.622730
2017-06-30 00:00:00,4.772234,0.000000,-1.033943
2017-07-31 00:00:00,4.772234,3.448276,0.253271
2017-08-31 00:00:00,6.997930,-1.666667,-0.526316
2017-09-30 00:00:00,4.247291,5.084746,-2.476190
2017-10-31 00:00:00,4.377417,0.000000,-0.462963
"""

data_io = StringIO(data)
df = pd.read_csv(data_io)
print(df)
```

**Reference:**

[How to drop a column if there is more than 55% repeated values in the column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71384876/how-to-drop-a-column-if-there-is-more-than-55-repeated-values-in-the-column)

Comment: What is exactly the issue in one or two sentences? It's unclear from your question.

Comment: Sorry, `remove_columns_with_too_many_duplicates(df1, threshold=0.3)` should return empty dataframe, since all the columns with duplicate value ratio greater than 0.3. But my code return `val3`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your exact issue is unclear, but what about using:

```
def flag_duplicates(s, threshold=0.4, precision=None):
    if precision is not None:
        s = s.round(precision)
    c = s.value_counts(normalize=True, sort=False)
    return ~ s.isin(c.index[c.gt(threshold)])

flags = df.filter(like='val').apply(flag_duplicates, threshold=0.3)
```

Output:

```
    val1   val2   val3
0  False  False  False
1  False  False  False
2  False  False  False
3  False  False  False
4  False   True   True
5  False   True   True
6  False   True   True
7   True   True   True
8   True   True   True
9   True   True   True
```

To keep the columns without any duplicate:

```
out = df.loc[:, flags.all().reindex(df.columns, fill_value=True)]
```

Output:

```
                  date
0  2017-01-31 00:00:00
1  2017-02-28 00:00:00
2  2017-03-31 00:00:00
3  2017-04-30 00:00:00
4  2017-05-31 00:00:00
5  2017-06-30 00:00:00
6  2017-07-31 00:00:00
7  2017-08-31 00:00:00
8  2017-09-30 00:00:00
9  2017-10-31 00:00:00
```

To keep the **rows** without any duplicate:

```
out = df[flags.all(axis=1)]
```

Output:

```
                  date      val1      val2      val3
7  2017-08-31 00:00:00  6.997930 -1.666667 -0.526316
8  2017-09-30 00:00:00  4.247291  5.084746 -2.476190
9  2017-10-31 00:00:00  4.377417  0.000000 -0.462963
```

Comment: Great, you seem to be close to giving the correct answer I need. But what I need is to delete the column if the duplicate value contained in it exceeds the threshold, instead of deleting the row.